# How to move Composer created folder of drupal-8.x.x up one level to html?

Tags: drush, composer

So I created a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and installed the LAMP stack, installed phpmyadmin and composer and then finally drush. Everything worked fine until I downloaded and installed Drupal using the "drush pm download" command which worked fine but now my entire drupal site is located in a folder called "drupal-8.6.3". I used to use the wget command and the tar --strip components command to get it properly organized.

I can delete the drupal-8.6.3 directory but how can I download my drupal site using composer or drush from the html folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `composer` to manage dependencies, you should install Drupal with Composer instead of using `drush pm-download`:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#download-core

Also, you should use Composer to manage contributed modules instead of using `drush pm-install`:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#managing-contributed

You can even use Composer to manage third-party libraries:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#third-party-libraries

And to apply patches to Drupal core and contrib modules:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#patches

Don't worry, you'll still use `drush` for a lot of things -- but once you've switched to using Composer to manage dependencies, you should stick with it as much as possible and avoid using Drush makefiles or installing / upgrading with Drush.

Here's an article with some common "gotchas" you may encounter when managing Drupal with Composer:

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/composer-and-drupal-are-still-strange-bedfellows

Comment: One more question as I am working on my home server right now...I have followed the composer command: composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev my_site_name_dir --stability dev --no-interaction and it worked. But now when I go into the html root using my web browser I get a directory listing. Should I change the Document Root in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file? There is also a new "web" folder that I've never seen before.

Comment: The `web` directory is your new Document Root. Go ahead and change your Apache 2 config to reflect that. Remember to edit the conf file in `sites-available` because the entry in `sites-enabled` is a symbolic link generated by `a2ensite`.

Comment: Everything is working now, I made the necessary changes in sites-available.conf and added this line at the end of the settings.php file: $config_directories = array(CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/files/config_HASH',);

Comment: Hmm, OK. I meant to edit `sites-available/000-default.conf` if that was the one you were using. But I'm glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: Matt - I made the changes to the sites-available/000-default.conf file and drupal wouldn't install because it couldn't create the /config/sync folder. So I googled and found the solution. Now can drush change the permissions back or do I manually put them back?

Comment: Personally, I recommend using `chmod` to manage permissions, and keep them to the minimum possible -- don't go around setting everything to `chmod 777` just to get things working. You may need to add your user to a group such as `www-data` so you can use group permissions without needing to `sudo` all the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86239/discussion-between-kimosabe2016-and-matt-obert).